# Add check mark to action bar just like action mode

Tags: android

I'm looking to show the action bar "action mode" persistently throughout the life on an activity. This activity edits an image and once the user clicks the check mark the image is saved and the activity exits. However, if they press back the edit process is canceled.

My action bar is translucent with overlay content set to true. Here is how it looks.
[image]

**Here is what I have tried**
1. Action bar is translucent as well as my action mode. Action mode is overlayed causing a darkening of the action bar.
2. Make action bar transparent. Everything looks good but once you click the check mark you see an odd looking action bar without a background which is shown for a second.
3. Hide the action bar. This causes animation issues where you can see the action bar animate in while the activity is exiting.

All these attempts are hacks and they don't work well. Maybe I can somehow add the check mark on the left? I'm not sure how to reproduce that action mode as my action bar. Hopefully someone has a good idea on how I can achieve the action mode style.